# pexpect: lines missing from .before attribute

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm suspecting that that the far-end terminal device is doing something to confuse pexpect on the client side but I need some advise on how to confirm that.

Here is the problem:
The following is a snippet is from my terminal window when I run the command manually:

```
Xcvr# mdioFpgaXcvrRd bic1 0x806C 1
FPGA MDIO CFP read command: 
0x0001
Xcvr# 
Commands Supported: 
 <>-mandatory values []-optional |-or 
exit|quit 
   - exits/quits the CLI session 
fpgaRdReg <offset> <count>
```

superfluous help output continues for ~60 more lines ending with:

```
out [<filename>] 
  - Re-direct debugging output to file if specified, otherwise stdout 

Xcvr#
```

From the above snippet:

- `Xcvr#` is the command prompt
- `mdioFpgaXcvrRd bic1 0x806C 1` is the
  command that I typed in manually
- `0x001` is the output that I want to
  search for with pexpect
- everything else is superfluous output from
  the far-end

Now, I try to automate this with pexpect. The code goes something like this:

```
ssh_handle.sendline('mdioFpgaXcvrRd bic%s 0x806C 1' % bic_id)
ssh_handle.expect('Xcvr\# ')
ver_x_match = re.search(r'(?is)command:.+?0x(\w+).*', ssh_handle.before)
```

The expect call returns right away as it finds its pattern no problem. However, when I look at the .before or .after, or .buffer attributes of the spawn object, I see that the 0x001 output that I'm looking for is nowhere to be found. The buffer begins with the line right after that one as shown here:

```
 --- BUFFER ---

 --------------
 --- BEFORE ---

Commands Supported: 
 <>-mandatory values []-optional |-or 
exit|quit 
   - exits/quits the CLI session 
fpgaRdReg <offset> <count>
```

continues for ~60 more lines end with:

```
out [<filename>] 
   - Re-direct debugging output to file if specified, otherwise stdout 


 --------------
 --- AFTER ---
Xcvr# 
 --------------
```

At the end of the day, what I'm trying to figure out is what is happening to the first few lines right after the command line. It seems like they are getting gobbled up somewhere in the pexpect buffering. I'm wondering if the far-end terminal is messing up pexpect somehow but I don't know to verify that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hmmm...doing some more debugging here and I'm starting to think that ssh_helper.buffer has stale data in it causing confusion for subsequent expect() calls. Does anyone know how to ensure that the buffers are pristine before initiating a new sendline() sequence?

Comment: try calling `read_nonblocking()` before `sendline()`.

Comment: Thanks but I figured out the problem after doing more debugging. It turns out the far-end device was feeding null characters (\x00) in the output. The null characters were not visible when running the command manually on a terminal but they were screwing up the pexpect pattern matching. I created a new pexpect regex expression to handle the \x00 characters and now all is working.

Comment: but how the *superfluous help output* was printed?